# Switching from SQLite to Firebase?

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, firebase

So for my Android App which stores data of workouts I have been using a SQLite Database so far. Now I want to implement these features:

1. Offer workouts in real time (with Firebase Database)
2. Being able to access your data on other devices and maybe from an web app 
     later

I figured, that for this purpose Firebase would be a great fit. But switching from SQLite to Firebase would bring a few down sights in my opinion:

1. Every user would need to sign up. I think for some users this is a reason to 
     not use my app. There is no way to avoid having to sign up when using 
     Firebase to store the data for user, right?
2. I´m not sure how good the offline options of Firebase Database is. How long 
     will the data be accessible without a connection? Is the capacity and 
     performance comparable to a SQLite Database?

I thought an alternative way could be to use Firebase just for offering the workouts but keep the data about a workout (repetitions, weight, ...) in a SQLite Database. Then I could upload the Database File with Firebase and another Device could download and continue it. Could that be an option?

Any thoughts and advice are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every user would need to sign up. I think for some users this is a
>   reason to not use my app. There is no way to avoid having to sign up
>   when using Firebase to store the data for user, right?

Right. (Technically it *is* possible, however you will need to enable read / write operations to non registered uses which is a no-no and not recommended at all.)

> I´m not sure how good the offline options of Firebase Database is. How
>   long will the data be accessible without a connection? Is the capacity
>   and performance comparable to a SQLite Database?

From the firebase database docs: *Firebase apps automatically handle temporary network interruptions. Cached data is available while offline and Firebase resends any writes when network connectivity is restored.*.

So yes, you can continue writing to it even when offline and read the already cached data, but this does not solve your concern that users will have to register to use the app.

## Possible solution

Use both SQLite and Firebase database:

1. For a registered user, always write in both SQLite and Firebase to keep them in sync (write in Firebase first and then SQLite). Another option is to write in SQLite and sync to Firebase every X minutes. Read data from Firebase when online and from SQLite when offline.

   When the user is offline, you will to write data to SQLite. You will need to mark those records as non-synced so that next time it is connected you will write them to firebase.

   Also, when reconnected, you'll need to somehow *merge* firebase data (that might have changed) and local SQLite data. The algorithm for this depends on your app.
2. For non-registered users, use SQLite only.

The downside to all this is that the complexity of your application increases a lot. It's up to you to decide whether it's worth it or not. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! About the caching of the data: I knew about that, but that only works when I start the app with a connection so its not really an option for an "offline modus". I could mybe realize and offline modus with `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);` , I guess I will have to test this.

Comment: @user9216568 No problem. Could you accept the accept if it helped you?